# Всплывающее окно не отображается magnific-popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть несколько товаров с кнопкой заказать, при нажатии ничего не происходит, и ещё вопрос как можно передать название именно того товара на который кликнули в значение скрытого инпута?

```
<div class="catalog__item">


<div class="img-catalog-block-item" style="background: url(img/red.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
                             <div class="sale"><span>-50%</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px">Товаров осталось: 9</p>
                        <div class="product-info clearfix">
                            <h5 id="prod">Товар 1 </h5>
                            <h4>399<span>800</span></h4>
<div class="catalog__item">
                        <div class="img-catalog-block-item" style="background: url(img/red.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
                             <div class="sale"><span>-50%</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px">Товаров осталось: 9</p>
                        <div class="product-info clearfix">
                            <h5 id="prod">Товар 2 </h5>
                            <h4>399<span>800</span></h4>
```

И сама форма для заказа

```
<div class="hidden">
            <form id="modal_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" required><br>
                <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер" required><br>
                <button>отправить</button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Стили формы:

```
.hidden
{
    display: none;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Код js

```
$(".popup").magnificPopup();
```

подключил magnificPopup и JQ

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: А сам `JQ` подключил?

Comment: Да, извините забыл добавить

Comment: Какая ошибка в консоли? Предполагаю, что `Magnific` работает с помощью JQ, поэтому JQ нужно подключить до Magnific.

Comment: @mix, спасибо помогло переподключил всё заработало, но сама форма прикреплена к верху и не реагирует на position:fixed или absolute, она прикрепилась к верху, подскажите как исправить?

Comment: Магнифик, видимо, грузит свои стили, поэтому форма прилипла в одном месте. К сожалению, могу только догадываться о причинах такого поведения, поскольку не вижу вашу форму.

Comment: @mix так и есть, я просмотрел код, все стили от магнифик как это можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте для теста, жестко задать css свойства с помощью `!important`, если удастся добиться реакции, то я был прав в пред комменте.

Comment: @mix цвет не изменился

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91156/discussion-between-alexander-and-mix).